# Permission denied when trying to make sublime text shortcut

Tags: macos, terminal

So I just started getting into using terminal to manage files etc, and I was trying to setup my sublime text shortcut using this  line of code:

`ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime`

However, when I try to  do this it says Permission Denied and I have no idea why. I am using a Mac running `Mac 10.10.2`.

Answer (score 7):

For sublime text 3:

`sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime`

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the permissions on `/usr/local/bin` you will see it is owned by `root`:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ ls -l .
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 8 root  wheel  272 Apr 16 11:31 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Apr 16 10:02 include
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  102 Apr 16 10:19 share
```

Therefore you need to use `sudo` to gain super user privileges.  You will need to enter your user account password and you will need to be an *Admin* user (see *System Preferences* > *Users & Groups*):

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin
```

Note that you don't need the trailing `subl` on the destination as `ln` will figure that out itself.

Comment: will using sudo mess up my computer in any way? Sorry not that experienced with terminal or root directories or anything.

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting this error. "The files /Users/MukilLoganathan/cs61a/lab/lab01/Text and /Users/MukilLoganathan/cs61a/lab/lab01/2 do not exist."

Comment: Well you've done something completely different then as that folder is not involved in this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac, I would suggest creating a file `/usr/local/bin/sublime` or somewhere else on your `PATH` and putting `open -a Sublime\ Text $@` inside instead of creating a link.  `open -a` tells Mac to open an application that is in your `/Applications/` directory.  and the `$@` symbol passes on any additional arguments that you supply to the script.  Thus, you can open a file by doing `sublime file.ext`.  That said, it is possible that your permission denial is that you don't have permission for the `/usr/local/bin` directory.  If that is the case, you need to change the permission using `chmod`, or just put the script somewhere else like `~/bin`

Comment: I tried to use tht method as well before and it would not let me create a file on my Path.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you're using Sublime Text 3, this is the correct command for the symlink:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```